# Maui Push Notification open push how to navigate to HomePage with parameters

Tags: ios, push-notification, navigation, maui

We have a Maui Application that has received Push Notification. When we open the Push Notification, we need to navigate to the 'HomePage' with parameters. The default start page is 'HomePage' without parameters.

This works on Android. On iOS, the OnAppearing method of HomePage is not called.
How can we force the navigation to open/call the OnAppearing method of HomePage?

If the last page in navigation stack is another page (for example 'SettingsPage') the navigation to the 'HomePage' on iOS works when opening the push notification.

We have tried to delete the navigation stack and then navigate to the 'HomePage' with parameters.

This doesn't work, the OnAppearing is not called.

Comment: You can try to override [OnNavigatedTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.onnavigatedto?view=net-maui-8.0)  in  HomePage instead.